# Only fire jQuery function in responsive view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I use a responsive design. I have three blocks next to each other. When the viewport gets smaller, the blocks will align under each other.

Then, I hide the content of the third block (with CSS). When the heading of this block is clicked, the content appears.

This function should only work in the responsive view. I use two breakpoints, to know which one is active I created two elements: `#rd-m` and `#rd-s`.

The CSS for them is:

```
#rd-m, #rd-s {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 73em) {
    #rd-m {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
    #rd-m {
        display: none;
    }
    #rd-s {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

So my function should only work when `#rd-s` is visible

```
$(function() {
    if($('#rd-s').css('display') == 'block') {
        $(".search-bar>div:nth-child(3) h2").on("click", function() {
            if( $("[usemap='#map-nl']").css('display') == 'none' ) {
                $("[usemap='#map-nl']").slideDown('slow', function() {
                    $('map').imageMapResize();
                });
            }
            else {
                $("[usemap='#map-nl']").slideUp();              
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This all works on page load. If I look with a small viewport, the function fires, when I look with a big viewport it doesn't.

But when the page is already loaded, and the viewport gets resized, the function doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: How about moving the display/block check inside the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `('display') == 'block'` check outside the *click* handler, the handler doesn't get loaded if the element is not displayed. Instead move the condition inside the *click* handler so it always loads, then check for `('display') == 'block'` every time the *click* handler is executed.

```
$(function() {
    $(".search-bar>div:nth-child(3) h2").on("click", function() {

        if($('#rd-s').css('display') == 'block') { // now checking inside the handler

            if( $("[usemap='#map-nl']").css('display') == 'none' ) {
                $("[usemap='#map-nl']").slideDown('slow', function() {
                    $('map').imageMapResize();
                });
            }
            else {
                $("[usemap='#map-nl']").slideUp();              
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch jQuery **resize** event by this function:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {

   //your function

});
```

In your case I thin you shoud use something like in this fidle:

http://jsfiddle.net/626B2/875/

(Look at JS code)

EDIT: Please remember that maybe you will need IFs for JS code onresize.

In example:

```
if (window.width() > 300) {
  //my code
}
```